# car hire database design, require guidance on how to implement vehicle and employee tracking

Tags: mysql, database, erd

I am working on another project that involves a car hire company which can be summarised as followed:

- A depot supplies cars to multiple hire points and acts as a service garage for repairs
- A hire point can use many depots for servicing and the supply of cars
- A customer makes a rental for a car from a hire point and can return the car to the same hire point or a different one of their choice. The system must keep track of where the car currently is.
- Vehicle availability and repair/maintenance status must be recorded.
- A discount must be able to be added to cars for promotional events
- The database must keep track of employees who are either depot employees or hire point employees. a hire point employee may work at a number of hire points during the week and is given a schedule a month in advance, whereas a Depot employee remains at the same location.

I have attached an ERD of what I have so far and would like some comments on its structure please.
I am having difficulty in understanding how I am going to keep track of the cars, and how I am going to implement a shift pattern for employees for both the depot and the hire point with the above requirements.

kind regards

[image]

Comment: Minor: at quick glance, I would update 'Vehicles' to 'Vehicle'. Overall, any table name set as plural (Discounts, Payments) I would rename as singular (Discount, Payment).

Comment: Regarding 'implement a shift pattern for employees for both the depot and the hire point', would you elaborate?

Comment: I think the employee management part can be an entirely separate system

Comment: Each employee is either at a depot or a hire point. If it is a hire point employee then they may be required to work at many different hire points during the week so the system must keep track of where they are. If it is a depo employee, they remain at one depo throughout their employment.

Comment: @HappyCoding actually the table names should be plural (the contain a list of Vehicles), but the (probable) corresponding object should be singular, what do you think?